# HTML Footer issue, div background not occupying fully

Tags: html, css, web, footer

**Check my Current Issue here** (image attached)

[image]

The footer background color is not occupying fully.

The HTML COde is :-

```
<div class="footer">
        <p class="footer-txt-left">&copy 2017 - 2018 ccc Group Inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p class="footer-txt-right">Terms | Privacy | Service</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:-

```
.footer{
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
            background-color: #0071ba;
        }
```

I want both span should be comes inside footer div (filled with blue BG color)

**Below is my expected Output**
[image]

FUll CSS:-

Attached my Full CSS HERE Below

[image]

**Full CSS snippet**

```css
  .footer {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #0071ba;
    color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .footer-txt-right {
    float: right;
  }

  .footer-txt-left {
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p class="footer-txt-left">&copy 2017 - 2018 ccc Group Inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p class="footer-txt-right">Terms | Privacy | Service</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to run it and it full fill

Comment: But for me the background is not covered the span :(

Comment: you are using float, so clear float --> `overflow:auto` on footer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good Point....missed that.

Comment: @Fabio_MO did you at least check his code an question before using snippet? there is no need to convert code to snippet as it's clearly don't show the behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif  where i'm using float? i have not used any float in footer css

Comment: it was a guess ;) and it you didn't provide us with full code, so share all your code and we will see if it's float or not

Comment: @TemaniAfif i have attached my full CSS, please check it

Comment: @TemaniAfif im always facing this issues in div, teach me  why so i can learn.

Comment: and you are using float :) check the code you shared

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, to make text go left i use float left , and to make text right i used flot right in footer. Anything wrong i did? :(

Comment: nothing wrong and as I said it's a clearing float issue .. you need to clear float